# Crear editText con texto superior que cambie de color al ser pulsado

Tags: android, xml

Me gustaría crear un edittext con texto superior que cambie de color cuando sea pulsados como en la siguientes imágenes:

Pulsado:

[image: pulsado]

Sin pulsar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado el siguiente archivo .xml en la carpeta drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#84868C" />
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <!--<gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#DD2C00" android:endColor="#FFAB00" />-->
    </shape>
</item>
```

Pero no consigo establecer el texto en la parte superior, ni tampoco sé qué atributo debería usar para cambiar para usar un color u otro en función de si el botón es pulsado o no. Podéis echarme un cable? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esto se puede realizar de forma nativa con un [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout)

Agrega un selector llamado textfield.xml dentro de `res/color/` que cambie de color azul o gris dependiendo de si esta enfocado o no el `EditText`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#0000CC" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#E0E0E0" />
    <item android:color="#E0E0E0" />
</selector>
```

ahora crea dentro de `res/values/` tu archivo `styles.xml` y modifica o agrega el siguiente tema:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
    <style name="outlinedTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/textfield</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/textfield</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textfield</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Esta sería la vista `TextInputLayout` que agregarías a tu layout usando el estilo `outlinedTextInputLayout` :

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:counterEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Nombre o ID Ficha"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

---

Lo anterior se mostraría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]